# How to convert type `file` in arg parser from Python 2 to Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to convert an xsd to a PostgreSQL schema, for which I found [this Python script](https://github.com/mikeshultz/xsd2pgsql/blob/master/xsd2pgsql.py). Unfortunately it's a Python 2 script, so I want to convert it to Python 3. It fails on this part however:

```
parser.add_argument(
    'xsd', 
    metavar='FILE', 
    type=file,
    nargs='+',
    help='XSD file to base the Postgres Schema on'
)
```

The error says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "xsd2pgsql.py", line 183, in <module>
    type=file, 
NameError: name 'file' is not defined
```

I know there's no type `file` any more in Python 3. How can I fix this?

Comment: You probably shouldn't have used `file` in Python 2, either. Use `argparse.FileType` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `type` argument will accept any callable which will take the string used on the command line and return some object of the desired type.

So in this case, just doing `type=open` would be equivalent to the action of `type=file` in Python 2, which is to return the handle of a file opened in read-only mode.

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('infile', type=file)
args = parser.parse_args()

print(args.infile.readline())
```

gives:

```
$ python2 test.py /etc/passwd
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash

$ python3 test.py /etc/passwd
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 5, in <module>
    parser.add_argument('filename', type=file)
NameError: name 'file' is not defined
```

After changing to `type=open`

```
$ python3 test.py /etc/passwd
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
```

(This will also work with python 2.)

However, a greater range of file opening options is available using  `argparse.FileType` (see [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html)).

This needs to be instantiated, so the basic usage is `argparse.FileType()`, but for example you could use `argparse.FileType(mode="w")` (or just `argparse.FileType("w")`) to get a file opened for writing.  So this code:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('outfile', type=argparse.FileType(mode="w"))
args = parser.parse_args()

args.outfile.write("hello\n")
args.outfile.close()
```

would give this:

```
$ python3 test.py myoutput
$ cat myoutput 
hello
```

although this would not be necessary for conversion of the Python 2 example in the question.

Answer (score 1):

`argparse` comes with a file wrapper that will open a file for you.

```
parser.add_argument(
    'xsd', 
    metavar='FILE', 
    type=argparse.FileType('r'),
    help='XSD file to base the Postgres Schema on'
)
```

This would have been preferred in Python 2 as well.